# Does php send a cookie to localhost with HTTP when session_start() with cookie_secure equal to true?

Tags: php, cookies

If I start a session like below for a server and a localhost client try to request the server via `HTTP`, does it response with the `session cookie`?

or must it go through HTTPS?

I read the [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure) and it did say only through HTTPS, but I wonder if localhost is an exception.

```php
session_start([
    'cookie_secure' => true
]);
```

Comment: PHP as such doesn't even really know what it runs on; `cookie_secure` sets a flag on the cookie itself, which is interpreted and (hopefully) obeyed by the *browser*. So, if anything, a *browser* may make an exception. But AFAIK they usually don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does:

[image: Network pane in browser developer tools]

If you try this in a browser, you'll also see a warning saying that the cookie was rejected.

This makes sense because PHP has no control on the entire communication channel and it's possible that the end-user is connecting to a secure proxy that redirects internally to a non-encrypted HTTP server.

Comment: Thanks. Also, It turns out Browser will accept `secure cookie` when the response is from localhost such as `http://localhost:xxxx/`

Comment: @ikhvjs That's right: [Restrict access to cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed the cookie is send to the browser either way in the *first* interaction. It is left to the browser to interpret what to do with the settings. But setting `cookie_secure` has no effect: the cookie is send and effective (Chrome 122.0.626.95).

There is a secure way to make sure to prevent interpretation of the cookie and that is by prefixing the cookie name with '__Secure-'.

See a [repo](https://github.com/theking2/php-secure-session.git) that tests these scenarios.

Make sure to have a cookie manager handy to view and delete cookies.